# bash script to take file as input and show all lines with no

Tags: bash, shell

Right. Basically what I want to achieve is i am trying to write a bash script which will take file as input argument and then load that file in the script and show all the lines in that file with the numbers bulletin. how can i do that.
i have tried nl -ba teat file but its not working

```
 1  hii
 2  whats up
 3  how are you today 
 4  where have you been 
 5  whats going on
```

this is the sript i have written

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# == 0 ]; then
echo "ivalid argument"
elif [ $1 == $file ]; then
while read line
do
echo `nl $Line`
done
else
echo "wtf" 
fi
```

Comment: Are you looking for `cat -n file`?

Comment: or `awk '{printf NR" "$0"\n";}' file`

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Hi Dhirendra, What output do you get? In script $file is has no value, script must exit with error @ line "elif [ $1 == $file ]; then".

Comment: yeah but i am looking to implement it into the script so that i can use file as variable and show the lines in it with the number

Comment: ./load.sh testfile |   testfile is the file wich i want to load in $file which can be taken as varible and then show the no. of lines from testfile  with no at bigining

Answer (score 1):

See below modified script that does the job without using "nl":

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "ivalid argument"
  exit 1;
fi;

cnt=1;
while read line; do
  echo "$cnt $line";
  ((cnt++));
done<"$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, what

```
[ $1 == $file ]
```

is supposed to mean in your script, since you don't set a variable `file` anywhere, but here is one solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
nl -ba {$1?Tell me the name of the file or I will kick you}
```